# What is the quality (specifically acidity) of FSC paper?

Tags: printing, paper

I am trying to establish the acidity of paper produced with the FSC labels and any help regarding this would be greatly appreciated. I am interested in figuring out the lifetime and decay of this paper. Thanks.

Comment: This is not about writing. You might get better answers on Graphic Design SE, or at the FSC site itself. https://us.fsc.org/en-us

Comment: IMHO, publishing questions, including materials, are on-topic here. (although as far as I can tell this one specifically seems mis-aimed). That being said, @LaurenIpsum is quite right that other sites may be better venues for questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> FSC 100% means that all the wood in the product comes from FSC-certified forests.
>
> FSC Recycled means all the wood or paper in the product comes from reclaimed material.
>
> FSC Mix means at least 70% of the wood in the product is from FSC-certified material or recycled material; and 30% is controlled wood.

As far as I can tell, the FSC label tells you something about where the materials came from, but nothing about the actual quality of the paper. "FSC 100%" paper would presumably have exactly the same qualities as non-FSC paper made from non-FSC wood, and using precisely the same process from that point on.